# Preventing Group Policy Override in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

**Background:** I have created Group Policies for both Admin and Non-Admin user accounts on a workstation. These workstations will be sent to foreign networks at a Hospital. I would like these group policies to remain and not be overridden.

**Some questions:**

- Can the group policies on the
  workstation be overridden if attached
  to a network that has these set
  already?
- If yes, how can I prevent
  this?

Comment: The workstation will still need to share folders with other computers in the workgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make sure these computers aren't joined to the hospital's domain. They would need to be used as outside PCs even if the user is authenticating with hospital credentials. It would create significant inconvenience if the user needs to access network resources regularly.

What exactly is the gaol of setting these policies on your end?

Comment: @Garett these computers will need to be connected to the Hospital internal network PACS for imaging. The group policies on our workstation are in place to restrict access to certain parts of the OS so that our custom clinical software can only be used. As a result we do not some foreign group policy to be pushed to our system.

Comment: You should be fine to connect to their network, as long as you aren't joined to their domain.